# Cycle through functions for each list item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python.

Given a list of items, `item_list` I am trying to run a function on each of them and these functions should come from `function_list`:

```
item_list = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6]
function_list = [myfunction1, myfunction2, myfunction3]
```

I would like somehow to loop through the items and associate a function to them: 
It should results in calls like this:

```
myfunction1(item1)
myfunction2(item2)
myfunction3(item3)
myfunction1(item4)
myfunction2(item5)
myfunction3(item6)
```

So the first item in the list it would launch `myfunction1()`, the second item `myfunction2()` until it gets to the end, it would then start picking the functions from the beginning.

Anyone have an example of something similar I can see?

Comment: `for item in item_list: for function in function_list: function()`

Comment: Do you want to run *each* function for each element, or do you want to run one function per element and cycle through elements?

Comment: One function per element

Answer (score 6):

You can zip and cycle. Later iterate through:

```
from itertools import cycle
... etc ...

for item,func in zip(items_list, cycle(functions)):
    func(item)
```

Here is a complete example:

```
from itertools import cycle

def myfunction1(item):
    print("f1", item)

def myfunction2(item):
    print("f2", item)

def myfunction3(item):
    print("f3", item)

functions = [myfunction1, myfunction2, myfunction3]

items_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for item,func in zip(items_list, cycle(functions)):
    func(item)
```

This will allow to start picking functions from the beginning when you reach the end.

Comment: With this I get the error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: let me know if that works or share the piece of code that you are using

Comment: What does x represent?

Comment: It is just the argument of the function. I am renaming that to item to make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a list of the functions you want to run, and then call them in your loop:

```
functions = [function1, function2, ...]
for i, item in enumerate(item_list):
    functions[i % len(functions)](item)
    # other code
```

Using `i % len(functions)` makes it loop back to the beginning.

Comment: That will not work if you run out of functions

Comment: Running out of functions was not defined.  He would probably *want* an error to occur, so that he notices that he didn't put the right functions in the list.

Comment: He said:  "until it gets to the end, it would then start picking the functions from the beginning."

Comment: I didn't notice that.  Thanks for mentioning it.  I modified my answer.

Comment: you need to pass the item to the functions. Otherwise you could just execute them without traversing the item_list just by using the length of the list.

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed that, too.

Answer (score 1):

with a queue :

```
from collections import deque
f=deque([f1,f2,...])
for item in item_list :
    f[0](item)
    f.rotate(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` is useful for this, but it is perhaps easier to see and read if it is written natively

```
funcList = [foo1, foo2, bar1, bar2] # each of these are functions

for i, item in enumerate(itemList):
    funcList[i % len(funcList)]()
```

Just to be cute, if you have functions that you know are named sequentially, you can do something like this (assuming these are global functions):

```
funcList = [globals()["myfunction{}".format(i)] for i in range(1, 8)]
```

I would not actually deploy this, though.

Also, it appears that you don't even have to iterate through the items themselves. What you should do, if this is the case, is simply iterate through a range:

```
for i in range(len(itemList)):
    funcList[i % len(funcList)]()
```

Comment: If you take a look at the comments on his question, you will see that he doesn't want to call each function for each iteration.  He wants just one function per iteration, but that one function should be different each time.

Comment: @zondo edited. The OP was not clear and I was writing it as the comments were posted.

Comment: Now you have the same problem I had.  You probably didn't notice, but the OP mentioned _until it gets to the end, it would then start picking the functions from the beginning._

Comment: This keeps on using the list list_item for some reason, it ignores all before it

Comment: I'm not sure as to what that means.